# \begin{note} in beamer does not work

Tags: beamer, theorems

Here is a sample code. In frame 1, we used  `\begin{note} . \end{note}` command. I expect to see a block like theorem environment. I am using XeLaTeX Engine.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer} % 160mm x 100mm
%%%
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
%%%
\usepackage[minalphanames=3,maxalphanames=4,maxcitenames=3,maxbibnames=99,style=alphabetic,hyperref,backref=true,backrefstyle=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{bm} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{shadow} 
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usepackage{ulem}
%%%
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
%%%
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{proposition}{\bf Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition} 
\newtheorem{exercise}{\bf Exercise}
\newtheorem{algorithm}{\bf Algorithm}
\newtheorem{question}{\bf Question}
\newtheorem{axiom}{\bf Axiom}
\newtheorem{property}{\bf Property}
\newtheorem{assumption}{\bf Assumption}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{\bf Remark}
%\newtheorem{note}{\bf Note} % Already defined
\newtheorem{claim}{\bf Claim}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
% Frame 1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\frame[t]
{ \frametitle{Note does not work in beamer}
Hello.
\begin{note}
 Note that "note" does not work in beamer. Why?
\end{note}
Hello.
\begin{theorem}
 Theorem works well.
\end{theorem}
}
% Frame .. %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\frame[t,allowframebreaks]
{ \frametitle{References}
\printbibliography
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

Comment: `\note` in `beamer` is a macro taking one argument, not an environment.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should clean up your preamble. A lot of the package aren't necessary in a beamer document.

Comment: @campa, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A note in beamer is a macro with a special purpose: to create speaker notes on separate pages or screens.

If you want to create a theorem-like environment for notes, you should choose another name, e.g.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer} % 160mm x 100mm
%%%
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
%%%
\usepackage[minalphanames=3,maxalphanames=4,maxcitenames=3,maxbibnames=99,style=alphabetic,hyperref,backref=true,backrefstyle=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
%\usepackage{amsfonts} 
%\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
%\usepackage{amsthm} 
%\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{bm} 
%\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{shadow} 
\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usepackage{ulem}
%%%
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
%%%
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition} 
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{property}{Property}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}

\newtheorem{mynote}{Note}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{series=\bfseries}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
% Frame 1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}[t]
 \frametitle{Note does not work in beamer}
Hello.
\begin{mynote}
 Note that "note" does not work in beamer. Why?
\end{mynote}
Hello.
\begin{theorem}
 Theorem works well.
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]